# How to reduce the height of the list elements in dropdown

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have tried to override the height for the list items of the dropdown
[dropdown list width and height overrided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZTre.png)

```
 .ui-list{
           max-width : 200px
           max-height : 200px
     }
```

but only the height is not getting overridden
[styles not override for height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEVjq.png)

Comment: Try to put `max-height: 200px!important`

Comment: @umgolla-You can use custom css for this.You need to override below class by inspecting  <span class="ui-list ci ni sn be so bg ja jb jc jd db au av aw ax jj jk jl jm ap aq ar as bp nj jw ji a nk sp ui-dropdown__items-list"/>as follow: 
.ka {
    height: 2.2857rem;
} However it is not the ideal way to do so.

Comment: thanks you, it works, i would like to know, if any standard way of doing it apart from this

Comment: @MarkoSavic, both worked. 
for the first one i had conflict with other list

Comment: There is no another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom css for this.You need to override below class by inspecting.

```
<span class="ui-list ci ni sn be so bg ja jb jc jd db au av aw ax jj jk jl jm ap aq ar as bp nj jw ji a nk sp ui-dropdown__items-list"/>
```

as follow:

```
.ka 
  { 
   height: 2.2857rem; 
  }
```